# How to redirect to an external url along with POST argument without building any form in drupal?

Tags: php, redirect, drupal, drupal-7

I am trying to talk to a gateway. For this I am first taking clients information then procesing it. After processing is done I redirect user to another blank page where I fill up hidden form fields with parameters for 3D secure connection which then redirect user to third party page. Hence there are 3 redirection. I want to remove 2nd redirection and instead send post data to url with redirection without building any form. I am looking into drupal_http_request, but it seems it only posts parameters and don't forward user to action url.

What can I do?

Comment: I would use a custom module and curl.

Answer (score 0):

drupal_http_request() does allow POST but it defaults to GET. It also returns redirect url if the returned request specifies one. I'd give drupal_http_request() in a custom module a try though before resorting to curl.

Comment: i want to redirect user to the page as well with post parameters. without any forms.